# Timesnaps change to string even when the simulation run time includes the date and time

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I want to import arrival data using an excel sheet[part of the data in excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKFiF.png) but the time snaps being in the valid format of date, still change to string [in anylogic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btmqX.png).

I have tried figuring out the actual format of the date format by creating a table in the database. The date format in DB table looks like [db table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/628DL.png) while copying the same cell in the excel shows [excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NGlL.png). I have checked the early query which got resolved because the simulation time was not in the range but I have included the dates according to the data imported.
I want to know what format I should enter data in an excel sheet so that it is in the valid format of date type in AnyLogic. Please clarify how to import it such that it remains in the date format, as I have spent a lot of time figuring this out.

Answer (score 0):

This heavily depends on your Excel setup, language settings, locale...

Easiest way: Create a new AnyLogic dbase table with a date column manually, fill it with some dates manually and export it to a separate Excel file. Check the format it appears there and try to re-import it into a dbase table. Then, it should be recognized as a Date again.

(These date exercises are always tedious and 99% of the time it is an Excel issue)

Comment: Yes, it recognizes it as the date, but I have about 700 rows and can't enter data manually (presently I'm getting this sheet from python script). Although the format is the same it still shows in string. @benjamin

Comment: Well, then you need to either change your Excel settings until it works or change/postprocess the data so it shows in the right Excel format so AnyLogic picks it up.

Comment: I tried all possible ways I knew, do you know some other way to import this type of data in excel to define arrivals and then later use in the model?

Comment: There in the database table, it shows this: 21-02-2023 08:00:00, while copying from the database and pasting into excel it shows this in the respective cell: 2023-02-21 8:00:00 and corresponding to this it shows 2/21/2023 8:00:00 up in the formula bar. What should I do now?

Comment: Not clear, sorry. Either edit this question to share more details or open a new one with detailed screenshots, what you tried...